# How to get 4 distortion elements with opencv camera calibration?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, distortion

I use 5 elements distortion for my stereo camera and I find there is a little contort on the corner of the correction image(especially the left camera),  while 4 elements distortion matrix is fine.
[5 elements correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG3sM.jpg)
[4 elements correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n34X2.jpg)
Above tests are implemented on MATLAB, and I need to code on python with openCV.

The problem is that I consulted the openCV documentation, which mentioned the 4 elements distortion, but did not provide the corresponding flag.
I doubt whether openCV can really generate a 4 elements distortion matrix?

Comment: If you have the distortion coeffs and want to pass them to cv.undisrto, just do it, pass an array of 5 elements. If you want to calibrate your camera using `cv.cameraCalibrate` in such a way that returns 5 elements of distortion, take a look at flag options at https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga3207604e4b1a1758aa66acb6ed5aa65d

Comment: I may have made a mistake, look at distort parameter of cv.undistort in https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga69f2545a8b62a6b0fc2ee060dc30559d
You may need to create a bigger vector and set a few parameters to zero

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV's `calibrateCamera()` function has flags( `CALIB_FIX_K1`, ... , `CALIB_FIX_K6`) to omit specific radial distortion coefficients from optimization parameter.

This is described in OpenCV's reference manual as

> CALIB_FIX_K1,...,CALIB_FIX_K6 The corresponding radial distortion coefficient is not changed during the optimization. If CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS is set, the coefficient from the supplied distCoeffs matrix is used. Otherwise, it is set to 0.

Therefore, you will be able to exclude unnecessary radial distortion term with the flag (and giving 0 as initial value).